# How to run json-schema-validator from the command line

Tags: java, json, validation, jar, json-schema-validator

Is it possible to run the json-schema-validator from the command line?

Is there a jar file for json-schema-validator? I found a jar at:

```
 [http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-validator/2.1.8][1]
```

but it appears to be corrupt/incomplete/something (I'm not a Java programmer). Applying java.exe to the jar file:

> ```
>  java -jar json-schema-validator-2.1.8.jar
> ```

results in this error message:

```
 "no main manifest attribute, in json-schema-validator-2.1.8.jar"
```

What does that mean?

Here are my questions:

1. Where can I obtain the correct jar file for json-schema-validator?
2. Once I obtain the jar file, how do I use it on a command line to validate a json file against a json-schema file? That is, on the command line I would like to type something like this:

> ```
>  java -jar json-schema-validator-2.1.8.jar instance.json schema.json
> ```

and have the validator validate **instance.json** against **schema.json** and display the results of the validation on the command line.

Thanks!

Comment: not all jars are executable. If there isn't any command line processor, you can still write yours, add to the jar and make it executable - see http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/

Comment: (author here) As we discussed by mail, this is a planned feature for 2.2.0; stay tuned ;)

Answer (score 2):

OK, since version 2.1.10 you can actually do that. Instructions are provided in [the README of the project](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/blob/master/README.md). Here is the help of the current version:

```
$ java -Done-jar.silent=true -jar json-schema-validator-2.1.10-standalone.jar --help
Syntax: java -jar jsonschema.jar [options] file [file...]

Options: 
    -s, --brief: only show validation status (OK/NOT OK)
    --help: show this help
    -q, --quiet: no output; exit with the relevant return code (see below)
    --syntax: check the syntax of schema(s) given as argument(s)

Exit codes:
    0: validation successful;
    1: exception occurred (appears on stderr)
    2: command line syntax error (missing argument, etc)
    100: one or more file(s) failed validation
    101: one or more schema(s) is/are invalid
```

Comment: With 2.2.x the synopsis is clearer - the schema file is listed first:     java -jar jsonschema.jar [options] schema file [file...] (where the jar is really the /json-schema-validator-${JSV_VERSION}-lib.jar file that is executable and contains all the dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try build and install C++ https://bitbucket.org/gallen/libvariant tool, that solve your problem.

Cli command - varsh