# JSON validation with custom schema

Tags: json, validation, schema, command-line-interface, jsonschema

I simply want to validate a `JSON` file with the proper `JSON` schema I have written, just to check if I did everything right. Is there a command line tool or anything else for this (I'm on Ubuntu)? Everything I found yet, are packages for several programming languages for writing validation methods in code. 
 I just need a tool where I can specify my `JSON` file and my custom `schema` and check it. That's it...

Comment: there's a quite helpful website: http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. Please have a look at [json-schema validators implementations](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html) to find the one that most suits your needs.

You can use [fge java json schema validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) from the command line as [it is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867521/how-to-run-json-schema-validator-from-the-command-line).

If you are comfortable with python, you can also use [jsonschema python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema) and run it from any python console:

```
from jsonschema import validate
validate(json, schema)
```

Another popular [javascript library is tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4). You can use it directly in the browser, or [in node console](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tv4).

```
var valid = tv4.validate(json, schema);
```